# fileExistsAtPath:filePath method of NSFileManager keep returning NO

Tags: ios

1. Menus.plist file in bundle;
2. copy the file to URL_DocDir_MenusPlist;

   ```
   (#define URL_DocDir_MenusPlist [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Menus.plist"])
   ```
3. go to the Document Directory and the plist exists, but

   ```
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: URL_DocDir_MenusPlist.absoluteString]
   ```

   method keep returning NO.

PS. in device and in simulator.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: if i use Str_DocDir_MenuPlist instead.( #define Str_DocDir_MenuPlist [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Menus.plist"]),then return YES. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the property `absoluteString` with returns the full URL including in the scheme (`file://`).

The correct property for `fileExistsAtPath` is `path`

```
URL_DocDir_MenusPlist.path
```

Side notes:

1. I'd recommend `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` of `NSURL` instead of `fileExistsAtPath`
2. Please use the Cocoa naming convention:

   - Variable names starting with a lowercase letter and camel case rather than underscore separation.
   - Constants or macro names with the entire name in uppercase letters and underscore separation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the 'Side notes':1->i will try it.2->i should use URL_DOCDIR_MENUSPLIST.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the prefix in the name could not be start with "URL", which is Build in keyword preserved by Apple.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think it`s not the reason. the difference: URL_DocDir_MenusPlist.absoluteString is like ' file:///var/mobile/xx' and Str_DocDir_MenuPlist is like '/var/mobile/xx'